# Angular UI Bootstrap TypeAhead for Multiple Arrays

Tags: angularjs, arrays, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui-typeahead

Having an issue getting the Typeahead feature working properly in UI-BootStrap with large datasets.  I've got nearly 92,000 records coming back and it seems the maximum number of records that can be in an Array is 10000. So that means I have 10 arrays that contain data.

[image: Large Array of Data]
However, currently I am only able to search through any one Array...so if I set it to response.data[0] that means I am going to be missing 81,000+ records to run typeahead on...

I'm sure there has to be a way to set it so that it can:
A) Either put the data in a single array for it to work with 
OR, preferably:
B) wait until the user types in a certain number of keystrokes, say 3, and then do a "Get" call to the server with that data, and only bring back the data that matches those 3 keystrokes, which will likely be far lower than 10,000 items for it to search through...

Can anyone help with either scenario? Preferably Scenario B?

Comment: i don't know what you're trying to show with that screen shot, the text is just way too small to see anything.  maybe crop the image (use window's snipping tool) or post your code into the question

Comment: All you have to do is click on it and it becomes bigger

Comment: If your data is loading from a remote destination just go with 2nd method. Perform search with the entered keyword. Plus what's the point of sending 10k+ elements anyway ? I mean, in reality does it really have any significance ?

Comment: OK, but how exactly would I set that up?